# Unity script to move a 3D object doesn't completely go to plan

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and Stack Overflow, and was looking for a script that will make an object(like a player), move. I have found a script that works, well, kind of works or went to plan. When I tested the script out, when ever I pressed forward on the arrow keys, instead of going forward, it will just start jumping. If I press the down arrow key, the cube(or player) will try to push itself under the ground, and then will fall forever, but the left and right arrow keys are working perfectly fine. Please note that this script for now is only for moving the player, and nothing else, just in case you were thinking it was supposed to something else or different. Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {


    public float moveSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        moveSpeed = 5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        transform.Translate(moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
}
```

I hope you find a solution or can find an explanation. Thanks for replies.
Regards, 
        User:9104031

Answer (score 2):

#### Unity uses a coordinates system where Y is up and Z is forward.

[image]

In your code, you are moving your player based on your "Vertical" axis input on the Y axis, which would of course map your UP/DOWN arrow keys to the wrong direction.

All you have to do is change

```
transform.Translate(
    moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime
    , moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime
    , 0f);
```

to

```
transform.Translate(
    moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime
    , 0f
    , moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this is what you'll want in your update section:

`transform.Translate(moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * Time.deltaTime, 0f, moveSpeed * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);`

I swapped your Y and Z axis. Hope that's what you were going for!